# type object 'Task' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

Am starter in Django and tried `CreateView` class and got the following error: Am unable to  find the issue. `ListView` and `DetailView` works fine.

Trace Log :

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 20, 2022 - 22:38:33
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'configs.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /task/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 32, in get_form
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 101, in get_form_class
    return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 563, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 261, in __new__
    fields = fields_for_model(
  File "C:\Users\mayank.shah\.virtualenvs\TASKS1-M_IXiD8r\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 150, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'Task' has no attribute '_meta
```

model :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user =models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True,related_name='usertasks')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task-app:task', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-create']
```

view :

```
class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    model = Task
    # fields = "__all__"
    fields = ('title', 'description')
    # fields = ['title']#,'description','completed']
    success_url= reverse_lazy('task-app:tasks')
```

Comment: Check that you haven't named one of your other views `Task` there could be a naming conflict

Answer (score 0):

Dear All the issue is Task is Key-word and so  causing issue. I renamed the model as alltask and it fixed the issue.  Though this is not faced by all, but can be useful if no solution found.